# CRXDE doesn't allow me to upload/download bundles

Tags: aem, crx

**Version AEM 6.3, this is my local instance.**

Everytime I go into AEM to install a bundle on my local it says exec.json is missing, I found a manual override for the issue, but it's doubled my time to integrate bundles.

**Error**

**Creating Package**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
service/exec.json?cmd=create:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Dialog.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined
    at constructor.CRX.ide.Dialog.DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLER (Dialog.js:191)
    at Object.callback (ext-base-debug.js:1443)
    at Ext.form.BasicForm.afterAction (ext-all-debug.js:56465)
    at Ext.form.Action.Submit.failure (ext-all-debug.js:58865)
    at Ext.data.Connection.handleFailure (ext-all-debug.js:8564)
    at handleTransactionResponse (ext-base-debug.js:2517)
    at ext-base-debug.js:2552
```

**Installing Package**

```
ext-all-debug.js:8665 POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/exec.json?cmd=upload&jsonInTextarea=true 404 (Not Found)
doFormUpload @ ext-all-debug.js:8665
request @ ext-all-debug.js:8853
(anonymous) @ ext-base-debug.js:751
run @ ext-all-debug.js:59008
(anonymous) @ ext-base-debug.js:831
setTimeout (async)
defer @ ext-base-debug.js:864
doAction @ ext-all-debug.js:56328
submit @ ext-all-debug.js:56384
doSubmit @ UploadPackageDialog.js:56
submit @ Dialog.js:128
onClick @ ext-all-debug.js:41008
h @ ext-all-debug.js:2463
VM420:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at doDecode (ext-all-debug.js:11527)
    at Object.decode (ext-all-debug.js:11649)
    at Ext.form.Action.Submit.handleResponse (ext-all-debug.js:59055)
    at Ext.form.Action.Submit.processResponse (ext-all-debug.js:58876)
    at Ext.form.Action.Submit.success (ext-all-debug.js:59024)
    at runCallback (ext-all-debug.js:8652)
    at Ext.data.Connection.cb (ext-all-debug.js:8656)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.h (ext-all-debug.js:2463)
```

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more precise how you install the bundle? Where do you do it? Do you install a content package or the jar file?

Comment: It's on my local, and it's the 6.3 jar file that AEM offers, I install the local using the QuickStart AEM install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue, by finding an old blog: https://aemgeeks.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/install-crx-packages-bundles-automatically-on-server-startup/

**Steps**

1. Create an `install` folder at the root of crx-quickstart folder.
2. Place package you're trying to install in the `install` folder.
3. Restart AEM local.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it from `console/bundles`.

Comment: Hey there, I've tried it. There's a manual work around for this issue, but I still can't create packages, is it possible that it can be a permissions thing, but at a local level, maybe my computers firewall has some sort of impact?